# "dyld: Library not loaded... Incompatible library version" when compiling with -frameowork

Tags: c, macos, clang, sdl, dyld

I'm have this source file

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)) {
        printf("Hello SDL\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have the latest SDL2 installed in `/Library/Frameworks`.

I successfully compile using:

```
clang main.c -o game.out -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2
```

When I try to run game.o (`./game.out`) I get this error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2
  Referenced from: /Users/Timothy/game/./game.out
  Reason: Incompatible library version: game requires version 2801.0.0 or later, but SDL2 provides version 1.0.0
Abort trap: 6
```

I don't understand why I'm able to compile but then when I run I get an incompatible version error.

Comment: It links without the flag because you are not using it. Use a bare minimum from SDL and try again, you will have to link against `SDL`

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question. I still get the problem where it will compile and then not run due to an incompatible version.

Comment: Can you check the `rpath` ( Potentially it points to the older version) ?

Comment: How can I do that?